# Methods with different names but all calling the same method

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I have the honor to maintain the code of a former employee. I see several methods which do exactly the same but all have different names:

```
public DocBuilder comment(String co){
    //some code
    return this;
}
public DocBuilder cmnt(String co){
    return comment(co);
}
public DocBuilder c(String co){        
    return comment(co);
}
public DocBuilder reference(String name) {
    //some code
    return this;
}
public DocBuilder ref(String name) {
    return reference(name);
}
public DocBuilder r(String name) {
    return reference(name);
}
```

and many more like attribute, element ... with at least 3 additional "abriviated" methods each.

I know this has nothing todo with method overloading as the args are all same type and length.

What I don't understand is the sense behind it. Why do I need 3 or more methods with different abbreviations if they all call the same unshorted method anyway? To type faster? Doesn't almost everyone use code completion? Or is this some code writing pattern I don't know yet?

I can delete almost two thirds of the lines without breaking the class logic.
What is the profit of such code repetition?

Comment: We can't tell you why a former employee wrote questionable code.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a name for it like `Builder pattern` `factory pattern` and so on but for the above way of coding.

Comment: Better to avoid unreadable coding practices like that for good of your coworkers.

Comment: Perhaps it was published code, people complained about the `long` method names, so s/he put in a shorter version but had to keep the older one for backward compatibility.  Of course, in that case, the older one should have been tagged as `deprecated`.

Comment: There is a name for it, it is called an *anti-pattern*,

Comment: I think you should have asked the former employee ... and "I can delete almost two thirds of the lines without breaking the class logic" but maybe break other classes calling these methods, since these are `public`. But it's sure not the best (I now know that `c()` stands for comment, but only now and because I have seen the code, and what is `p()` ((assuming there is one)))

Comment: mark as deprecated and delete in future versions... or, if not a *library* or so; use refactoring to inline the calls (I believe most IDEs can do that) A bit of work now, better than *trouble* later

Answer (score 0):

Some points about strange code:

- Be aware! There are a lot of ways to use this code (i.e. reflection, aspects). Perform such clean-up if you're pretty sure that nothing is affected. If not, a better choice is to add some comments and notes.
- Use static code analysis tools that should help you to identify [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). For example [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)
- Do test to ensure that business needs are satisfied. After performing tests, you can check code coverage and remove redundant code